# Задержка при наведении мышкой на всплывающее окно hover или как это решить?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, блок

Есть блок, при наведении показывается другой, коричневый, блок.
В коричневый блоке есть текст. Но но ее не выделить, потому что когда мышка там, она уходит.

```css
    [data-tooltip] {
        position: relative; /* Относительное позиционирование */
        
    }
    [data-tooltip]::after {
        content: attr(data-tooltip); /* Выводим текст */
        position: absolute; /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
        width: 300px; /* Ширина подсказки */
        left: 0; top: 0; /* Положение подсказки */
        background: #925836; /* цвет фона */
        color: #fff; /* Цвет текста */
        padding: 0.5em; /* Поля вокруг текста */
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); /* Параметры тени */
        pointer-events: none; /* Подсказка */
        opacity: 0; /* Подсказка невидима */
        transition: 1s; /* Время появления подсказки */
    }
    [data-tooltip]:hover::after {
        opacity: 1; /* Показываем подсказку */
        top: -6em; /* Положение подсказки */
    }
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<a href="" data-tooltip="Дневник тренировок и контроль достижений Дневник тренировок и контроль достижений Дневник тренировок и контроль достижений">Alexey Frolov</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалите `pointer-events` и тогда она не будет пропадать. Иначе все наведения и прочие события которые возникают при наведении, клике и т.д. на этот блок игнорируются. Но текст Вы всё равно не выделите так как, это сгенерированный контент псевдоэлемента.